# Using redux-form[v 6.0.5] getFormValues does not add values to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to add form values to props using getFormValues in my container. However, when I look for the values property in the derived component I get an undefined. What do I miss?

The container code:

```
import {reduxForm, getFormValues} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/propertiesActions';
import Properties from '../components/common/Properties';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        form: ownProps.id,
        values: getFormValues(ownProps.id)(state)
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm()(Properties));
```

In the Properties component, calling `this.props.values` will return undefined.

What can be the problem?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prop «values» is reserved key in redux form. You need try to use some another key, like «formValues».

```
@connect(
  (state) => ({
    formValues: getFormValues('form-name')(state) || {},
  }),
  {}
)
@reduxForm({
  form: 'form-name'
})

export default class Form extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
    formValues: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot. I spent a lot of time debugging this. Thanks!

Comment: This is the first useful example using getFormValues I've seen. Thanks!